# DHCP categorise IP leases

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I would make a major upgrade in my home network environment. I have a dlink 655 router. On this router All the DHCP will be happening. Also I will have 3 additional APs.

I would like somehow to arrange the given IP leases in order. For example all wired connections, will have a range 50-100, Wireless devices will have 101-200, 2-49 will have Server/Services that will have opened ports on them etc.

Is that possible? It is also worth to mention that all the house will be wired through a 24port gigabit switch.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints in terms of hardware and IP make this untenable if you want to use a single IP LAN. In particular the constraints that all DHCP is on the dlink router, there are multiple APs, and that the Wifi devices are all (presumably) unknown in advance introduce issues.

If you Do know the macs for every device that will connect over wifi in advance, then this question is trivial (albeit maintenance heavy). just set up reservations for each mac in advance, assigning the IP you want. That is almost never a possibility for a modern home network, but if it is an option, its really the only way to achieve your ends given the other constraints.

Most home routers don't allow multiple address pools, and those that to tend to fill the first pool, and move on to the second in order of allocation, at least until it has collected a number of MACs. This is because the router only has two interfaces. In general you can only have one DHCP instance per interface, because otherwise how can the router determine which one the broadcast request frame is destined for? If you have a more sophisticated router, you can assign a server instance on any port you want, but then you are looking at routing between networks.

I have previously put wireless clients in a seperate range, by using the DHCP server on my wired router for wired clients, and enabled DHCP on my single AP, with a different pool range than the router uses. This mostly works, in that the AP offers before the router gets the request, but in some circumstances, that may not work perfectly, and the router might occasionally get the request, allocate an address etc. In your case though, you would need one DHCP instance per AP with a non-overlapping pool each. you could use a dedicated single wifi dhcp server, but that would require you to put the wifi on a different IP network.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something, but i doubt you can truly achieve what you wish.  Network card makers have ranges of mac addresses, as a result, you can therefore where the dhcp server allows have policys so that say aa bb goes to this dhcp scope and cc dd goes to another.  You may also be able to do it like my vigor in that you can have one dhcp for the wired network, and one for the wireless.

Otherwise, it would need to be done manually.

Im not sure of the functionality of your router.